# Коллекции не сохраняют добавляемые значения

Tags: java, form, коллекции, методы

Коллекции не сохраняют добавляемые значения
В методе public String pageReg1(Model model,@ModelAttribute RequestFormPassword form) 
Есть коллекция emails которая хранит в себе значения эмайлов.
Так в самом методе я добавил 2 эмайла прямо прописав их в ручную - вот они (emails.add("vasya@yandex.ru"); emails.add("sasha@yandex.ru");). И когда я печатаю коллекцию они с неё печатаются, но моя задача добавлять в эту коллекцию эмайлы, которые прилетают с сайта ( с формы ).
Т.е. я захожу на свою страничку http://localhost:8080/reg, там есть поле email ввожу туда эмайл и кладу его в переменную String prov = form.getEmail(); и добавляю значение этой переменной в коллекцию emails в одном из условий, но значение каждый раз перезаписывается вместо того что бы сохранятся.
Т.е. если я на своём локальном хосте ввожу эмайл vasa@gmail.ru и потом сново введу другой эмайл, он его перезапишет на место vasa@gmail.ru, хотя по идее должен бы записать оба значения в коллекцию.

```
package com.example.NewsApp.model.reg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

import com.example.NewsApp.controller.WebController;
import com.example.NewsApp.dto.RequestFormPassword;
import com.example.NewsApp.model.User;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class pageReg {


private ConcurrentHashMap<String, User> users = new ConcurrentHashMap<>() {{
    put("vasya", new User("vasya", "vasya@yandex.ru", "v123"));
    put("sasha", new User("sasha", "sasha@yandex.ru", "s123")); 
}};
private ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();

public String pageReg1(Model model,@ModelAttribute RequestFormPassword form) {

    model.addAttribute("form", new RequestFormPassword());
    String prov = form.getEmail();

    emails.add("vasya@yandex.ru");
    emails.add("sasha@yandex.ru");

    emails.add(prov);

    System.out.println("Печатаю мыло с формы + " + prov);
    for (var elem : emails) {
        System.out.println(elem);
    }

    if (users.containsKey(form.getLogin())) {
        System.out.println("Такой Login уже зарегистрирован");
        model.addAttribute("errorik", true);
        return "registering";
    } else if (emails.contains(prov)) {
        model.addAttribute("errorik1", true);
        System.out.println("Такой Email уже зарегистрирован");
        return "registering";
    } else {
        users.put(form.getLogin(), new User(form.getLogin(), form.getEmail(), form.getPassword()));
        emails.add(prov);
        System.out.println("Пользователь успешно зарегистрирован");
        model.addAttribute("sucsesful", true);
        for (var elem : emails) {
            System.out.println(elem);
        }
        return "signIn";
    }
}

public String pageSignIn(Model model, @ModelAttribute RequestFormPassword form) {

    if (!users.containsKey(form.getLogin())) {
        model.addAttribute("error", true);
        model.addAttribute("form", new RequestFormPassword());
        System.out.println("Блок 1");
        System.out.println(form.getLogin());
        return "signIn";

    } else if (!users.get(form.getLogin()).getPassword().equals(form.getPassword())) {
        model.addAttribute("error", true);
        model.addAttribute("form", new RequestFormPassword());
        System.out.println("Блок 2");
        return "signIn";

    } else {
        model.addAttribute("user", users.get(form.getLogin()));
        model.addAttribute("form", new RequestFormPassword());
        System.out.println("Блок 3");
        return "signIn";
    }
}
```

}
**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы на каждый запрос создаете новый объект `pageReg`, который ничего не знает об e-mail-ах, добавленных в коллекцию в предыдущие разы.

Comment: Игорь, т.е. при каждом новом запросе создаётся новый объект pageReg, который работает с коллекциями?
Я правильно понял?
Т.е. по сути каждый раз когда я делаю запрос это всё равно, что перезапускать каждый раз сервер ? При каждом новом запросе всё как с чистого листа?

Comment: @OlgaMechnekova Нет, это не то же самое, что перезапускать сервер.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, а что мне нужно сделать что бы вынести эти методы из контроллера в другой класс?